# Missing `count` method in Tkinter's Text widget

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to get the number of displayed lines in a Tkinter Text widget and I'm looking at this question:  [What's the most efficient way to get a Tkinter Text widget's total display lines after the insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428515/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-a-tkinter-text-widgets-total-display-lines)

The solution I'm interested in uses the widget's [count](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M72) method but on my Python 2.7.10 (Tk 8.5, Tcl 8.5) the text widget does not have that attribute.

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
text = Tkinter.Text()
text.pack()

def test(event):
    print "displaylines:", text.count("1.0", "end", "displaylines")
    print "lines:", text.count("1.0", "end", "lines")

text.insert("1.0", "a" * 81)
text.insert("2.0", "b\n")
text.bind('<Map>', test)

root.mainloop()
```

yields

```
AttributeError: Text instance has no attribute 'count'
```

From what documentation that I've found it should be there; have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Tkinter. You can use a monkeypatch to add the missing method:

```
def count_monkeypatch(self, index1, index2, *args):
    args = [self._w, "count"] + ["-" + arg for arg in args] + [index1, index2]

    result = self.tk.call(*args)
    return result

Tkinter.Text.count = count_monkeypatch
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  I was going a little bit crazy trying to understand what was going on.