# nltk.trigams has no count attribute

Tags: python, count, nlp, nltk, n-gram

I'm running `Python-3.x` on a `virtualenv`, trying to process text with `nltk`.

I saw this post [What are ngram counts...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821201/what-are-ngram-counts-and-how-to-implement-using-nltk) and the most upvoted answer has a bit of code using the `count()` method. but when I copy/paste it into mine:

```
import nltk
from nltk import bigrams
from nltk import trigrams

text="""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare
tempor lacus, quis pellentesque diam tempus vitae. Morbi justo mauris,
congue sit amet imperdiet ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare
tempor lacus, quis pellentesque diam"""

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tokens = [token.lower() for token in tokens if len(token) > 1]
bi_tokens = bigrams(tokens)
tri_tokens = trigrams(tokens)

print [(item, tri_tokens.count(item)) for item in sorted(set(tri_tokens))]
```

I receive this message:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'count'
```

I see [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784637/missing-count-method-in-tkinters-text-widget) on a monkeypatch for a count method but feel like that's somehow not related. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `nltk.ngrams`[returns an iterable generator](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/util.py#L462), see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/ and [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)

You should use a `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from nltk import ngrams
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = "This is a foo bar sentence".split()
>>> Counter(ngrams(s, 3))
Counter({('This', 'is', 'a'): 1, ('a', 'foo', 'bar'): 1, ('is', 'a', 'foo'): 1, ('foo', 'bar', 'sentence'): 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'count'` issue because **Generator** is destroyed after **first use** in python.

`tri_tokens is Generator`. It is used **twice** in your code.

```
print [(item, tri_tokens.count(item)) for item in sorted(set(tri_tokens))]
```

In above line of code, **tri_token** used **twice**. So, when you want to get **count** of item, your **generator** is already **destroyed**, after `(sorted(set(tri_tokens))` uses. That' why you get **AttributeError** issue.

So, **Best way** is to **convert generator to list**.

```
tri_tokens = list(tri_tokens)
```

Try below code:

```
import nltk
from nltk import bigrams
from nltk import trigrams

text="""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare
tempor lacus, quis pellentesque diam tempus vitae. Morbi justo mauris,
congue sit amet imperdiet ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ornare
tempor lacus, quis pellentesque diam"""

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tokens = [token.lower() for token in tokens if len(token) > 1]
bi_tokens = bigrams(tokens)
tri_tokens = trigrams(tokens)

tri_tokens = list(tri_tokens)

print [(item, tri_tokens.count(item)) for item in sorted(set(tri_tokens))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers didn't work for me, I ended up using:

```
bi_tokens = list(bigrams(tokens))
tri_tokens = list(trigrams(tokens))
```

after converting to lists it is possible to `count()`