# Python3/Tkinter text "displaylines" behavior issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to count the actual lines used in a text box when it is pre-filled with data, and again when the form is submitted.

With the code below, it incorrectly shows the number of lines as chars (93) when it starts, but when you push the count button it shows the correct number of lines (4).. from the same code execution. What am I missing?

```
import tkinter

text="adfa asdfkljds ;das asdjfkds fkldjasf dsf;dlsjfdkls jdkls fjd;lsfjd;ls fjd;lsafj ;dlsfj;asdlf"

def countit():
    print(DE.count('1.0', 'end', 'displaylines')[0])

top = tkinter.Tk()

DE = tkinter.Text(top, height=5, width=30, wrap="word")
DE.pack()
DEButton = tkinter.Button(top, text="count", command=countit)
DEButton.pack()        # WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED, CORRECT NUMBER IS DISPLAYED

DE.insert("1.0", text)
countit()              # FIRST RUN, INCORRECT NUMBER DISPLAYED

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`displaylines` can't be calculated if the data isn't displayed, since the value depends on various factors such as the screen resolution, the actual font (which might be different than the requested font), the size of the widget once `pack`, `place`, or `grid` and done it's calculations, and so on. These can't be determined until the window is actually mapped to the screen.

To illustrate the point, add `top.update()` immediately before calling `countit()` and you'll see that the value is correctly printed the first time.

A better fix would be to not call `countit` until the window has been mapped to the screen. For example, you can add this line of code after creating the text widget:

```
DE.bind("<Map>", lambda event: countit())
```

The above will call `countit()` immediately after the widget has been mapped to the screen.

Comment: The top.update works great.

When i try the <MAP> (with the top.update and initial call to countit commented out), it calls the function 3 times when the program runs, the first time has the wrong count but the other 2 are correct.  Why 3 times?

Comment: @MrT: it sounds like you bound `<Map>` to the root window rather than the text widget. If you bind to the root window, the binding will fire for every single widget. And if that happens, then the number will indeed be incorrect until the text widget is mapped (which is a microsecond or so _after_ the root window is mapped).

Comment: I'll blame the heatwave we are having..  binding to DE worked.  I'll figure out which one I am going to use. .Thanks for your help and quick response!